# Visibility div via 2 variables, different on / off

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm probably not fully awake so overseeing the obvious is possible. 
But I have 2 variables that decide if a div has a specific class or not.

The class is more acting like a toggle; so the following should happen to trigger the value:

```
focus            => on
!focus && !hover => off
```

So when the focus var turns on the class should be added, and when the focus is lost and the hover is off it should be removed.

I would preferably do it inline on the following place:

```
<div ng-class="{'visible' : --FORMULA-- }"> </div>
```

Here you should only see the "WOhooooo" once you've clicked the input box, and then it should only dissapear when you leave the grey box:
http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/MKYNqo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already know the syntax, dont know what did you try. This should work...

```
<div ng-class="{'visible' : 'focus', 'notvisible' : '!focus && !hover' }"> </div>
```

Comment: I tried doing it for only adding a single class, but that seems to work aswell

Comment: this isn't fully working apparently. making a codepen to checkout why